# Restrict assignment in if statements in Typescript

Tags: typescript, variable-assignment, compiler-options

Recently I caught a nasty bug caused by assignment in If statement. I consider if-assignment as a bad pattern for me and I want to turn it off completely to get the compiler varnings instead of actual bugs.

How can I do this in Typescript?

Answer (score 6):

I have found this option in TSLinter: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-conditional-assignment/